# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local'.'

Tags: c#

What im trying to do:
Make a program which has a feature that will allow the user to quickly delete a cache folder at a certain location. Issue, is the username or userprofile will be different for all. Is it possible to get it to fill in the "Current User" username/userprofile so its not throwing an error.

Sorry if this makes no sense, been up all night searching about for this and just cant seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the environment variables with

```
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local");
```

In your case (local app data), you could even use its own environment variable:

```
var path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%localappdata%");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-3.1